# Laravel forcing Http for asssets

Tags: laravel, http, url, https, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

this is a little bit strange because most of the questions here wanted to force https.

While learning AWS elastic beanstalk. I am hosting a laravel site there. Everything is fine, except that none of my javascripts and css files are being loaded.

If have referenced them in the blade view as :

```
<script src="{{asset('assets/backend/plugins/jquery/jquery.min.js')}}"></script>
```

First thing I tried was looking into the file/folder permissions in the root of my project by SSHing into EC2 instance. Didn't work even when I set the permission to public folder to `777`.

Later I found out that, the site's main page url was `http` while all the assets url were 'https'.

I dont want to get into the SSL certificates things just yet, if it is possible.

Is there anyway I can have my assets url be forced to Http only?

Please forgive my naiveity. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This usually happens if your site is for example behind an reverse proxy, As the URL helper facade, trusts on your local instance that is beyond the proxy, and might not use SSL. Which can be misleading/wrong.

Which is probaly the case on a EC2 instance... as the SSL termination is beyond load balancers/HA Proxies.

i usually add the following to my AppServiceProvider.php

```php
    public function boot()
    {
        if (Str::startsWith(config('app.url'), 'https')) {
            \URL::forceScheme('https');
        } else {
            \URL::forceScheme('http');
        }
    }
```

Of course this needs to ensure you've set app.url / APP_URL, if you are not using that, you can just get rid of the if statement. But is a little less elegant, and disallows you to develop on non https

Comment: i slightly modified it, as i didn't read it right, usually you want to use https instead of http.. but this should work in your case. with the else.

The origin of the issue is the same, as laravel gets confused by the cloud components that send headers between backends en endpoint balancers/ingress declarations